# uipath studio bot crash at the start of a new page

Tags: uipath-studio, uipath-robot

Hello I'am learning how to use uipath studio for work, but I have a problem when my bot starts a new chrome page.

The check state tells me that my button is here, he sees him but the task after the bot crash because he can see the ui element.

this problem happens only when it's start a new page on google chrome, i try to spit my worklow in 2 but with that i cant do the task i have (i have to switch between user to download files on his account)

I don't know I haven't found yet how to deal with it

Thx for help in advance